# Error TS2362: The left-hand side of an arithmetic operation must be of type 'any', 'number', 'bigint' (inside string interpolation {{ }})

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I hope you can help me with this error.

Chrome explorer prints this trace:

```
error TS2362: The left-hand side of an arithmetic operation must be of type 'any', 'number', 'bigint' or an enum type.

39       <div ngSwitch="{{e%2}}">
```

It is my **"app.component.html"**:

```
<mat-list role="list">
 <mat-list-item role="listitem" *ngFor="let e of lista; let i = index">
  {{i + 1}}::{{e}} - 
  <div ngSwitch="{{e%2}}">
    <div *ngSwitchCase="0" [ngClass]="'impar'">impar</div>
    <div *ngSwitchCase="1" [ngClass]="'par'">par</div>
    <div *ngSwitchDefault="0">Sin resultados.</div>
  </div>
  <button mat-stroked-button color="accent" (click)="remover(i)">Remover</button>
  <mat-divider></mat-divider>
</mat-list-item>
</mat-list>
```

**Additional info:**

- TS: "~4.5.2"
- Angular CLI: 13.1.2
- Node: 16.13.1
- Package Manager: npm 8.1.2
- OS: win32 x64

**OBS:** If I replace the modulus operator (%) by the plus (+), it compiles satisfactory.

Comment: Seems to me like `e` might be of type `string`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Though the type of `lista` is not provided in the question, it seems to be of `string[]` type, maybe something like:

```ts
    lista = ['0', '1']
```

If that's the case, then you will get an error while trying to perform `{{e%2}` , as modulus operator cannot be used on string operand. Same would be the case for other operators like `-`, `*`.

Now why `+` works is, because when used with string, it performs concatenation.

You can overcome the error by writing the interpolation as `{{+e%2}}`, provided it will always be a valid number within string, or else you will get `NaN`.